# convert regional characters into html entity with php

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

In my mysql database I have some data like this: `&aring;lesund` which is actually equivalent to ålesund. In the html I have ålesund. How can I search this in database with php? I have to convert å into `&aring;` in the query. like-

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfield = '&aring;lesund';
```

How can I do this with php?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like ...

```
$mystring = htmlentities('ålesund');

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfield = '$mystring'
```

... please note that this is not secure, look into escaping the string properly and using PDO

Comment: Note that you may need to use the charset argument as well